# Use of capture groups within lookarounds

Tags: regex, pcre

Suppose we are given the following string:

```
a, b, c, d
e, f, g, h
i, j, k, l
```

I wish to convert that to the following string using a PCRE regex:

```
ab, ac, ad
ef, eg, eh
ij, ik, il
```

More generally, each of these letters can be regarded as a placeholder for a string of word characters, and there can be an arbitrary number of them per line and an arbitrary number of lines.

If this cannot be done, can the following string be produced?

```
a, ab, ac, ad
e, ef, eg, eh
i, ij, ik, il
```

Please demonstrate your regex using the "SUBSTITUTION" facility (which can include back-references such as `$1`) at regex101.com. I would particularly appreciate an explanation of how the PCRE engine is stepping through the string.

If this cannot be done with a PCRE regex I would like an explanation of why it cannot be done.

I am asking this question to improve my understanding of how capture groups within lookarounds work.

Comment: I don't see any need for lookarounds. Just normal capture groups.

Comment: Just write a regular expression that matches two words separated by comma, optionally followed by another comma. Put the words and optional comma in capture groups, and copy them into the replacement.

Comment: "Please demonstrate your regex ..." sounds like you quoted it from an exercise, not a question of your own.

Comment: I didn't notice that each replacement contains the first word of the line, they're not in pairs. I don't think you can do this with a single regexp, they can't loop.

Comment: @Barman, I think that's because you are used to vague, ambiguous questions at this forum. I made up this question to gain an understanding of aspects of regular expressions that I don't understand, and attempted to make the question complete and unambiguous. Please accept it at face value.

Comment: It's trivial in any programming language with variables and looping, not trivial with just a single regexp replacement.

Comment: And as I said, I don't think it's possible. When you do multiple replacements, each of them needs to be a disjoint match in the source string, they can't overlap.

Comment: There's no way to capture the first field when matching each of the later fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can only be done with a regex engine that supports variable-width lookbehind patterns, which PCRE isn't. A variable-width lookbehind is required to reference the word at the beginning of each line for every subsequent word.

If variable-width lookbehind patterns are supported by your regex engine, you can then search for:

```
(?<=(\w+),.*)(\w+)|^\w+,\s*
```

and replace the matches with:

```
$1$2
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/XZhZyW/5/

Comment: You should consider posting a demo that works. I really want to upvote this answer but cannot in its current state.

Comment: Indeed. Fixed then.

Comment: I figured out the problem, I was using Firefox. Definitely add a footnote about browser support.

Comment: This is extremely helpful to my understanding. Basically, the lookbehind captures the first string of word characters and then, in some sense moves a pointer the engine maintains to the first match. If that's correct, can you explain the pointer aspect in some detail? I had previously thought that such a pointer would not move in a lookaround. One thing I had tried was to begin the regex with `(\w+){0}`, With that does the regex then attempt to match what follows with the beginning of the string?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think your explanation quite captures the essence of this regex though. The pointer always moves with every match, so we can't use a lookahead pattern since the pointer would move beyond the first word after the first match. With a lookbehind pattern we can then use `.*` to extend our reach backwards to the beginning of a line to re-capture the first word for every subsequent word in the line. The problem is that `.*` is of variable width, so this solution cannot be adapted for PCRE even if all words are of a fixed width.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean to do with `(\w+){0}`, since `{0}` means that the preceding group is to be matched zero time.

Comment: The explanation in your penultimate comment is both clear and appreciated. I thought that might set `$1` without being a match. Incidentally, I had noticed that you could simplify slightly, as you did with your edit. We have perhaps gone as far as we can here. I won't forget to select an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to mention a possible course of action when faced with a situation, as here, where a variable-length positive lookbehind is needed but the regex engine being used does not support that operation, but does support variable-length positive lookaheads, as does PCRE (PHP), for example.

I confess to mainly having written this answer to improve my own understanding of how regex engines operate.

**Basic idea**

- Reverse the string
- Use a regex with a corresponding positive lookahead to perform replacements of matches
- Reverse the resultant string

**Example**

Suppose we wish to convert the following strings:

```
a, bb, c, d
ee, f, g, h
i, j, kk, l
```

to the strings:

```
abb, ac, ad
eef, eeg, eeh
ij, ikk, il
```

We first reverse the original strings:

```
d ,c ,bb ,a
h ,g ,f ,ee
l ,kk ,j ,i
```

then match the regex:

```
(\w+)(?=.*,(\w+)$)|\s+,\w+$
```

and replace each match with `$1+$2`, to obtain:

```
da ,ca ,bba
hee ,gee ,fee
li ,kki ,ji
```

Lastly, reverse those strings:

```
abb, ac, ad
eef, eeg, eeh    
ij, ikk, il
```

[PCRE demo](https://regex101.com/r/XZhZyW/7/)

The regex performs the following operations:

```
(\w+)    # match 1+ word chars in cap grp 1 
(?=      # begin a positive lookahead
  .*,    # match 0+ chars (greedily), then ','
  (\w+)  # match 1+ word chars in cap grp 1
  $
)
|
\s+,\w+
$
```

I will represent the spaces in the string `"a, bb, c, d"` with little smilies (`☺`), to make them more distinct, and display the string thusly:

```
 a , ☺ b b , ☺ c , ☺ d
^
```

The spaces now represent the areas between adjacent characters. `^` is the initial location of the regex engine's pointer.

After `(\w+)` matches `"a"` at the beginning of the string (indicated by `m` below), `"a"` is saved to capture group 1. The positive lookahead begins right after that match:

```
 a , ☺ b b , ☺ c , ☺ d
 m^
```

The positive lookahead, `(?=.*,(\w+)$)` saves `"d"` to capture group 2.<sup>1</sup> As the match was successful, the first match, `"a"` is replaced with `$1+$2 #=> "ad"` and the pointer moves back to its position before the lookahead was executed:

```
 a , ☺ b b , ☺ c , ☺ d
  ^
```

There is now an attempt to match `(\w+)` with the part of the string that begins with the first comma. That fails, as does the *or* part of the regex, `\s+,\w+$`. The pointer is then advanced one character:

```
 a , ☺ b b , ☺ c , ☺ d
    ^
```

That also fails, and the pointer is again advanced by one.

```
 a , ☺ b b , ☺ c , ☺ d
      ^
```

`(\w+)` now matches `"bb"`, which is saved to capture group 1, at which point:

```
 a , ☺ b b , ☺ c , ☺ d
       m m^
```

As before, the positive lookahead saves `"d"` to capture group 2 and the match, `"bb"` is replaced with `$1+$2 #=> "bbd"`

After two more matching failures we are at:

```
 a , ☺ b b , ☺ c , ☺ d
              ^
```

For the same reasons as before, `"c"` is matched and replaced with `$1+$2 => "cd"` and we are now here:

```
 a , ☺ b b , ☺ c , ☺ d
                ^
```

There are no more word strings that are followed by word strings to be matched, but the end of the string, `", d"`, now matches the *or* part of the regex, `\s+,\w+$`. That match is then replaced with `$1+$2`. This time, however, the two capture groups are empty, so the match is replaced with an empty string.

<sup>1 The comma is needed. Without it, `.*`, being greedy, would gobble up everything before the last word character. If the string ended `", cd"`, for example, capture group 2 would contain only `"d"`.</sup>